# To get load-time of the test in Influxdb from Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

How do i get the load time of my test from jmeter into my influxdb. I am able to see data in influxdb that has been added from jmeter but how do i see the "load time" for my test case. The thing is if i run my test case 20 times, as number of threads:20, in influxdb 20 are divided based on number of threads per second, how can i change that. I want to see my load time for each test case in Influxdb-Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

In Jmeter just add a `Summary Report` to the existing `Recording Controller`. Then run the testcase. You'll see a row for each request and there would be a lot of information about the test including response time (Average, Min and Max)

[image]